# determine schema flavor - Looking for a miracle

Tags: xml

Any idea what is throwing this error?

Syntactic error in data: Can't determine schema flavor from root-element "PurchaseOrders in namespace "PurchaseOrders"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:PurchaseOrders xmlns:ns0="PurchaseOrders">
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="PurchaseOrderCount" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="TransmissionID" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="SenderID" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="ReceiverID" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="TimeStamp" type="xs:string"/>


end of file

    <xs:element ref="OrderDetail"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
</ns0:PurchaseOrders>
```